# Can I map keystroke to mouse event?

Tags: macos, mouseevent, keystroke

My OS Environment is Mac OS X 10.10.

I want to do some mouse event by a keystroke.
If I press a key, then the mouse will click on specific position automatically.
For example, left arrow keystroke, then click on (1000,500).

If possible, i want to make a program with above function. (in shell, python, applescript... etc)
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Solution might be using [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com) with Workflows in conjunction with a command line tool that emulates mouse events. I found this tool. [CliClick](http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/cliclick/)

Basicly what you would do is:

1. Add new workflow
2. Choosing Trigger --> Hotkey
3. Add an Action --> Run Script

have fun